# Android Preference Radiogroup

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-radiogroup

I would like to have a menu like the following:

[image: Menu to replicate]

How can I do that? I wanted to use PreferenceFragment but I'm starting to think that it's done in a different fashion... In particular I would like to have a list of radiobuttons with a "config" icon next to every Radiobutton (only the right part of the screen to be clear).

I'm looking at the Android source but without any idea... also a pointer would be appreciated :)

Thanks

Comment: This might help:  http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/11/android-shared-preferences-example_12.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be more feasible to use your own implementation than finding solutions/workarounds for a PreferenceFragment. Classic `ListView` with custom items should do it.